# How do I solve $4 \times 4$ simultaneous equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to find the equation of a cubic function. I have these four points:

$X= 0, Y= 20$

$X= 80, Y= 31$

$X=160 ,Y= 80$

$X= 240 ,Y= 93$

The equation for a cubic function is $y=aX^3+bX^2+cX+d$.
Using the co-ordinates above i managed to make these four equations:

1. (when $X=80, Y=31$) $\space 31 = ax80^3+bx80^2+cx80+d$
2. (when $X=160, Y=80$) $\space 80 = ax160^3+bx160^2+cx160+d$
3. (when $X=240, Y=93$) $\space93 = ax240^3+bx240^2+cx240+d$

And these are the four equations but in linear form:

1. (when $X=0, Y=20$)  $\space 20 = 0+0+0+d$ therefore $d=20$
2. (when $X=80, Y=31$) $\space 31 = 512000a+6400b+80c+20 (d=20)$
3. (when $X=160, Y=80$)$\space 80 = 4096000a+25600b+160c+20 (d=20)$
4. (when $X=240, Y=93$)$\space 93 = 13824000a+57600b+240c+20 (d=20)$

I know $d$ but I don't know $a, b$ or $c$, so if you know how to work these out please can you show me the calculations for a guide. Thanks!

Comment: Can you use the [Lagrange Polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)?

Comment: @Shane Winter: Do not create new accounts. Also, if you want to ask a new question, ask a new question. Do not deface the old question. Similarly, if you want to comment on one's answer, leave a comment. Do not deface their answer.

Comment: For the record, I suggested an edit adding the tags "cubics" and "system-of-equations", but [it was rejected](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2004296).

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways to do this problem, but I am going to follow your approach so you can see how to finish it up.

You are given the four $(x, y)$ points

$$\tag 1\{(0, 20), (80, 31), (160, 80), (240, 93)\}.$$

You are asked to find the equation of the cubic that passes through the four points in $(1)$.

A cubic is given by:

$$\tag 2 f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx +d.$$

**Point $(0, 20)$**

We have $f(0) = d =  20 \rightarrow d = 20.$

Note: we just use this immediately in subsequent calculations to reduce our system to a $3 x 3$.

**Point $(80, 31)$**

We have $f(80) = 512000 a + 6400 b + 80 c + 20 = 31 \rightarrow 512000 a + 6400 b + 80 c = 11.$

**Point $(160, 80)$**

We have $f(160) = 4096000 a + 25600 b + 160 c + 20 = 80 \rightarrow 4096000 a + 25600 b + 160 c = 60.$

**Point $(240, 93)$**

We have $f(240) = 13824000 a + 57600 b + 240 c + 20 = 93 \rightarrow 13824000 a + 57600 b + 240 c = 73.$

We can now write a $3x3$ system $A \cdot x = b$, where the vector $x = (a, b, c)^T$ as:

$$\tag 3 \begin{bmatrix} 512000 & 6400 & 80 \\ 4096000 & 25600 & 160 \\ 13824000 & 57600 & 240 \end{bmatrix} \cdot x = \begin{bmatrix} 11 \\ 60 \\ 73\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, use your favorite method (see **Update** below) to solve the system in $(3)$, yielding:

$$\{a, b , c\} = \left\{-\frac{37}{1536000}, \frac{13440}{1536000}, -\frac{627200}{1536000}\right\}.$$

We also obviously know $d = 20$, therefore,

$$\tag 4 f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx  +d = -\frac{37}{1536000} x^3 + \frac{13440}{1536000} x^2 -\frac{627200}{1536000} x + 20.$$

Of course, you should verify that $(4)$ produces the original four points in $(1)$.

Note: if we did not have a point $0$ to start with, we would have ended up with a $4x4$ instead, but the process is the same. You can use Gaussian elimination, inverses, or whatever method floats your boat to solve the matrix equation.

**Update**

I am not sure if you know any methods to solve the system in $(3)$, but we can use substitution, matrix inverse, Gaussian Elimination (Row-Reduced-Echelon-Form) and others.

For example, matrix inversion (typically frowned upon), yields:

$$x = A^{-1} \cdot b = \begin{bmatrix} 512000 & 6400 & 80 \\ 4096000 & 25600 & 160 \\ 13824000 & 57600 & 240 \end{bmatrix}^{-1} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 11 \\ 60 \\ 73\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{3072000} \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -3 & 1\\-1200 & 960 & -240\\115200 & -57600 & 12800 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 11 \\ 60 \\ 73\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{1536000} \begin{bmatrix} -37 \\ 13440 \\ -627200 \end{bmatrix}$$

Maybe you should try substitution and see if you can get that to work.

For the first equation, we would get:

$$c = \frac{-512000 a - 6400 b + 11}{80}.$$

We would substitute that into the second equation and solve for $b$.

We would then substitute $b$ and $c$ into the third equation and solve for $a$.

Give it a go, and report back if it does not work.

Regards

Comment: Nice work. I'm out of upvotes for today. I'll upvote you tomorrow.

Comment: @GitGud: thank you for the nice complement! Regards.

Comment: You killed the problem!! + 1

Comment: @amWhy: thank you. Was trying to figure out other ways to do it, but this actually seems the shortest for this variant. if it were 4x4, maybe a different story.

Comment: Kind of like I was saying yesterday, about my approach...you use it too: you often answer questions as though you are *conversing* with the OP, and that makes the site, I think, welcoming and personal. Like knowing there's a *person* "behind" the *post*!

Comment: @amWhy: To me, one of the best things we can do is to help posters grow and hopefully show them more clear ways of approaching problem solving, while at the same time encouraging write-ups that are clear, concise and complete.

Comment: You shifted from $a,b,c,d$ to $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ without comment.  Otherwise, this is a good answer.

Comment: @RossMillikan: yeah - I looked at that after the fact, and think I am going to change them back to $a, b, c, d$ because the OP started  with that and I should have too! Thanks for the nudge!

Comment: You are assuming OP knows about matrices and vectors, and has a method (even a favorite method!) for solving $Ax=b$. But perhaps this is precisely what OP *doesn't* have.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: good point! I suppose I should perhaps show one and will add it! Thanks!